# How to place image at Layout by java? Android

Tags: java, android, android-image

I have an image called c1.png in drawable-mdpi folder. I want to put it to layout by Java with this:

```
package ...;

import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(getCurrentFocus().getId() );

        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        img.setLayoutParams(lp);
        img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c1));
        layout.addView(img);
        setContentView(layout);//Doesn't matter, if it's commented or not. The error still exists.
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

I got: "Unfortunately, %application_name has stopped" when launched it. I saw many examples, using R.id.* in id params, but it stopped too (like R.id.linearLayout1), or R had not such constansts (like R.id.c1).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutID ); // //layoutID is id of the linearLayout that defined in your main.xml file

    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    img.setLayoutParams(lp);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.c1);
    layout.addView(img);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need not do a setContentView(layout); Also, replace :

```
findViewById(getCurrentFocus().getId() )
```

by

```
findViewById(R.id.layoutId); //layoutId is the id of the linearLayout defined in your layout.xml file. And R would refer to your local resources folder path and not the android Resources path.
```

You xml file could look something like this (this would be the main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If fact, my layout looks like RelativeLayout, not Linear

Comment: The main would have the relativeLayout and inside that you would have the linearLayout with the Id. Check me edited ans.

Comment: Well, it worked, but with the code of PAD only. I had to work with images in a different way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Use the code :**

```
 ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
 img.setImageResource(R.drawable.c1);
```